# Why the call to the php-file on the server does not work?

Tags: java, server, bufferedreader

I want to run php-file on a server from Android Studio. The file will add a string to the database and return the value 'success' if successful. I don’t see the point in uploading php-file – it processes a POST request. There are absolutely no errors in it. At first I made this code in the console and it worked perfectly. But when I copied it to Android Studio, it turned out that "D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default". This is strange because I just ran the same code in the console and there were no errors. But now the most interesting thing: if you replace the cycle that reads the input stream by reading one line, the error disappears. How it works? I thought that there was a request limitation on the server, but everything works from the console application. Maybe this is a feature of Android Studio?

```java
try {
    URL url = new URL("https://educationapps.site/hello.php");

    String postData = "username=" + username + "&email=" + email +
        "&password=" + password + "&func=" + func;

    byte[] postDataBytes = postData.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", 
        "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length",
        String.valueOf(postDataBytes.length));
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.getOutputStream().write(postDataBytes);

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(),
        StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

    // This code does not work ↓↓↓
    /*
    for (int c; (c = in.read()) >= 0;)
        System.out.print((char)c);
    */

     // But this one works ↓↓↓
     String c = in.readLine();
     System.out.println(c);

} catch (Throwable throwable) {
    System.out.println(throwable.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Does the response from the server end with a proper line terminator?

Comment: @StephenC, no, this is "success" or "error" without line terminator. But why you asking?

Comment: Because I think that the problem is output flushing.  `print` won't flush unless there is a line terminator.  `println` will flush.  (OK ... that depends on how the PrintStream has been configured ... but it explains why they *could* be different.)

Comment: @StephenC, I just checked php-file and made sure there is no line break there.

Comment: So, I think that is the explanation.  Add a `println()` after the loop and see if it fixes the problem.

Comment: @StephenC, I added the following line after the loop: `in.readLine();` but this also does not return a response from the server.

Comment: Get rid of the `readLine()` and add a `println()` after the loop and see if it fixes the problem.  (Seriously ... I don't know what you think that calling readLine after you have read all of the characters would do ...)

Comment: Got it! It really worked, thanks. But I still don’t understand why the line break is here? Does the Android Studio console not display the result until you pass a line break character?

Comment: And that's all, now I understand what you were talking about. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your comments, I think this will fix the problem.

```
for (int c; (c = in.read()) >= 0;)
    System.out.print((char) c);
System.out.println();

// and get rid of the 2 statements after this.
```

The problem appears to be that `System.out` is not being flushed.  `System.out` is a `PrintStream`, and a `PrintStream` can be configured to "autoflush" when line terminator is written.

- In your version with a `println(c)` you were *adding* a line terminator.
- When you ran the code from the command line, `System.out` was probably being flushed when `main` returned.

The Android Studio console behavior is ... well ... whatever it is.  But it is not a good idea for your code to make assumptions about how the console / console emulator is going to work.  Terminate your lines, or explicitly `flush()` or `close()` the output stream when you want to be sure that the data goes where it needs to go.